# Keeping track of (stack-allocated) objects

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, global

In a rather large application, I want to keep track of some statistics about objects of a certain class. In order to not degrade performance, I want the stats to be updated in a pull-configuration. Hence, I need to have a reference to each live object in some location. Is there an **idiomatic** way to:

1. Create, search, iterate such references
2. Manage it automatically (i.e. remove the reference upon destruction)

I am thinking in terms of a set of smart pointers here, but the memory management would be somewhat inverted: Instead of destroying the object when the smart pointer is destroyed, I'd want the smart pointer to be removed, when the object is destroyed. Ideally, I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

I could live with a delay in the removal of the pointers, I'd just need a way to invalidate them quickly.

edit: Because paddy asked for it: The reason for pull-based collection is that obtaining the information may be relatively costly. Pushing is obviously a clean solution but considered too expensive.

Comment: What kind of statistics do you need?  If it's just keeping track of a count of live instances, then consider storing a single atomic integer per class and maybe make a simple RAII wrapper to do the counting (that means you simply put it in your class definition and the work is done).

Comment: If it's any use, [here's a simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a25d7a6a2ec18a0) of what I was talking about.  It doesn't let you iterate or search your objects, but it's not clear why you want to do that.  Accessing another stack in this way is probably not a good idea.  This example just provides object counts with very low overhead, and thread-safe.

Comment: That would basically be a push-update, but is considered too expensive.

Comment: Updating a single atomic is going to be a hell of a lot less expensive than tracking all memory allocations and providing thread-safe statistics on demand.

Comment: Why do you insist on counting the objects? I want **some stats**, and these stats **are** expensive.

Comment: Well, see, I don't know.  You don't actually tell us what stats you want, so I had to assume you wanted counting.  I did ask, and you didn't comment, so I assumed I had inferred your intentions correctly.  Unless you give real information, I am more inclined to treat this as XY problem.

Comment: I've posted an answer that you may find useful.  I took the `Countable` idea from my example, and made it `Trackable` instead.  Now, a single stack can push objects onto a stack structure that you can iterate over as a linked list.  It's very lightweight, and might be the start of what you're looking for.  There are synchronisation issues the moment you want to use it from another thread, but I'm sure you can deal with it =)

Answer (score 2):

There is no special feature of the language that will allow you to do this.  Sometimes object tracking is handled by rolling your own memory allocator, but this doesn't work easily on the stack.

But if you're using only the stack it actually makes your problem easier, assuming that the objects being tracked are on **a single thread**.  C++ makes special guarantees about the order of construction and destruction on the stack.  That is, the destruction order is exactly the reverse of construction order.

And so, you can leverage this to store a single pointer in each object, plus one static pointer to track the most recent one.  Now you have an object stack represented as a linked list.

```
template <typename T>
class Trackable
{
public:
    Trackable()
    : previous( current() )
    {
        current() = this;
    }

    ~Trackable()
    {
        current() = previous;
    }

    // External interface
    static const T *head() const { return dynamic_cast<const T*>( current() ); }
    const T *next() const { return dynamic_cast<const T*>( previous ); }

private:
    static Trackable * & current()
    {
        static Trackable *ptr = nullptr;
        return ptr;
    }

    Trackable *previous;
}
```

Example:

```
struct Foo : Trackable<Foo> {};
struct Bar : Trackable<Bar> {};

//  :::

// Walk linked list of Foo objects currently on stack.
for( Foo *foo = Foo::head(); foo; foo = foo->next() )
{
    // Do kung foo
}
```

Now, admittedly this is a very simplistic solution.  In a large application you may have multiple stacks using your objects.  You could handle stacks on multiple threads by making `current()` use thread_local semantics.  Although you need some magic to make this work, as `head()` would need to point at a registry of threads, and that would require synchronization.

You definitely *don't* want to synchronize all stacks into a single list, because that will kill your program's performance scalability.

As for your pull-requirement, I presume it's a separate thread wanting to walk over the list.  You would need a way to synchronize such that all new object construction or destruction is blocked inside `Trackable<T>` while the list is being iterated.  Or similar.

But at least you could take this basic idea and extend it to your needs.

Remember, you can't use this simple list approach if you allocate your objects dynamically.  For that you would need a bi-directional list.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to have code inside each object so that it registers itself on instantiation and removes itself upon destruction. This code can easily be injected using a CRTP:

```
template <class T>
struct AutoRef {

    static auto &all() {
        static std::set<T*> theSet;
        return theSet;
    }

private:
    friend T;

    AutoRef() { all().insert(static_cast<T*>(this)); }
    ~AutoRef() { all().erase(static_cast<T*>(this)); }
};
```

Now a `Foo` class can inherit from `AutoRef<Foo>` to have its instances referenced inside `AutoRef<Foo>::all()`.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc480b11b3bc5560)

Comment: Much simpler than my solution =)  Although this does have logarithmic complexity.  I took them seriously when they complained that having one atomic increment and decrement per object was "too expensive".

Comment: Also, one problem both of our solutions suffer is that you cannot guarantee an object still in the registry isn't currently being destructed and is therefore invalid, even if you synchronise access across threads.  It's not hard to modify that behaviour, but it is a special detail worth considering.

Comment: @paddy OP doesn't want to eagerly push stats because they are slow to generate and ignored in most cases. No mention of counting or multithreading. The container can easily be swapped out for another depending on the usage patterns (insertion/removal rate, number of queries, etc).